# Clean up Eclipse's cache for Android

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm having trouble with Eclipse crashing too often whenever my device is attached to the USB. It's probably a driver problem but I would like to try out a few other things as well to resolve the problem. I would like to cleanup any cache directory that Eclipse and/or the Android SDK is using but not sure if one exists or even where it exists.

If one exists, how can I clean it up by deleting all the files in it?

Comment: I believe that that only cleans up the project and not Eclipse's own cache or any other caching stuff the Android SDK uses.

Comment: May be but according to your issue it could clear to run project. If you get issue check your code or post.

Comment: also this often happen coz of adb... adb has to be restart.. better adb kill and try

Comment: I actually clean my project all the time. The crashing has nothing to do with my project. Eclipse can just be sitting there doing nothing (or appears to be doing nothing) and then my entire PC crashes. I have noticed over time that it is most likely related to the USB connection. So yes, ADB may be part of the problem but if ADB is using some kind of cache, I want to clear it.

Comment: I don't have an idea about clearing adb cache but you can kill  and restart adb to clear in someway every-time you restart instead of re-install or other

Comment: Well I certainly don't need to kill adb after my computer crashes.